# API - CORS SESSION Problem with AJAX POST Requests

Tags: jquery, ajax, session, cors

i read many articles about CORS and AJAX and Headers, but nothing worked so far vor me.

My Problem:

i have Domain A, the php script on it sends an POST Request to DomainB.com/api/login to log into an API.
It gets an random Token back.
Then Domain A sends another POST Request to the Endpoint DomainB.com/api/endpoint1 to which it POSTS the Token to authenticate for the API, not for the website Framework. It also posts the portal username and password to login into the website framework and after successfully logged in, it gets the HTML View as response.

In the HTML there are jQuery AJAX Request, which fail (302 redirect to website login).
The website uses session.

The Webbrowser says:

```
Cookies with the SameSite=None; Secure and not Partitioned attributes that operate in cross-site contexts are third-party cookies. In future Chrome versions, reading third-party cookies will be blocked. This behavior protects user data from cross-site tracking.

Please refer to the article linked to learn more about preparing your site to avoid potential breakage.

1 Cookie

Name        Domain & Pfad
PHPSESSID   xxx.example.com
```

So the Browser with Domain A gehts the PHPSESSID, but cant resend it with the AJAX request in the HTML Scripts...

Headers are:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: ' . $origin);
header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, DELETE');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type');
```

the AJAX Request looks as follows:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://domainB.com/Controller/ajax_function",
    async: true,
    crossDomain: true,
    xhrFields: {
        withCredentials: true
    },
    data: {
        sessionID: '<?= session_id(); ?>',
        KBA: $('#hsn').val() + $('#tsn').val()
    },
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        
    }
});
```

I am expecting, that the AJAX Requests use the PHPSession and know, that im already logged in.